# Swift UITextField Border bottom and shadow issues

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that must have a bottom border. Since autolayout use my code is this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(0.5)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: txtUsername.frame.size.height - width, width:  txtUsername.frame.size.width, height: txtUsername.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    txtUsername.layer.addSublayer(border)
    txtUsername.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

This, however, excludes the fact that when I touch the UITextField, this should create me a shadow. the code is this:

```
    //ombra txtField
   self.view.addSubview(txtUsername)
    txtUsername.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 10)
    txtUsername.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    txtUsername.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    txtUsername.layer.masksToBounds = false;
    txtUsername.clipsToBounds = false
```

the one excludes the other. how do I fix?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CAShapeLayerShadow

```
func border(){
let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(0.5)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(1).cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CustomerTextBox.frame.size.height - width, width:  CustomerTextBox.frame.size.width, height: CustomerTextBox.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    CustomerTextBox.layer.addSublayer(border)
    CustomerTextBox.layer.masksToBounds = true

  }


   func shadow(){
    let Shape = CAShapeLayer()
     let myPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CustomerTextBox.frame)

    Shape.shadowPath = myPath.cgPath
    Shape.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    Shape.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 3)
    Shape.shadowRadius  = 5
    Shape.shadowOpacity = 0.8


    view.layer.insertSublayer(Shape, at: 0)

   }
```

[image]

Comment: all in a function? my problem is that the shadow needs are, open ONLY when I click on the textfield

Comment: you can put the part of the shadow inside another function